# Forming a request for API call from checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have html output in this i have to form a string that is used to for my api request as parameter.Below I have Given my html output:

```
<div class="right-filter-inner p-2">
<div class="right-inner-PROCESSING_TIME">
    <h4>PROCESSING_TIME</h4>
        <div class="top-checks rgt-report-sector" data-simplebar="init">
            <div class="simplebar-track vertical" style="visibility: visible;">
                <div class="simplebar-scrollbar" style="top: 2px; height: 25px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="simplebar-track horizontal" style="visibility: hidden;">
                <div class="simplebar-scrollbar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="simplebar-scroll-content" style="padding-right: 17px; margin-bottom: -34px;">
                  <div class="simplebar-content" style="padding-bottom: 17px; margin-right: -17px;">
                            <div class="filter-metrics">
                                <label class="custom-control">
                                    <input type="search" class="material-control-input filter-search" id="top-filter-search-PROCESSING_TIME">
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control material-checkbox filter-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input top-filter-all" value="all" checked="">
                                    <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                                    <span class="material-control-description">All</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control material-checkbox filter-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="PROCESSING_TIME" class="material-control-input filter-option top-filter-20181001" value="2018-10-01" id="top-filter-20181001" checked="">
                                    <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                                    <span class="material-control-description">2018-10-01</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control material-checkbox filter-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="PROCESSING_TIME" class="material-control-input filter-option top-filter-20181002" value="2018-10-02" id="top-filter-20181002" checked="">
                                    <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                                    <span class="material-control-description">2018-10-02</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control material-checkbox filter-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="PROCESSING_TIME" class="material-control-input filter-option top-filter-20180918" value="2018-09-18" id="top-filter-20180918" checked="">
                                    <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                                    <span class="material-control-description">2018-09-18</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control material-checkbox filter-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="PROCESSING_TIME" class="material-control-input filter-option top-filter-20180830" value="2018-08-30" id="top-filter-20180830" checked="">
                                    <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                                    <span class="material-control-description">2018-08-30</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-inner-DSPID">
            <h4>DSPID</h4>
                <div class="top-checks rgt-report-sector" data-simplebar="init">
                        <div class="simplebar-track vertical" style="visibility: visible;">
                            <div class="simplebar-scrollbar" style="top: 2px; height: 25px;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="simplebar-track horizontal" style="visibility: hidden;">
                            <div class="simplebar-scrollbar"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="simplebar-scroll-content" style="padding-right: 17px; margin-bottom: -34px;">
                            <div class="simplebar-content" style="padding-bottom: 17px; margin-right: -17px;">
                                    <div class="filter-metrics">
                                        <label class="custom-control material-checkbox filter-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="DSPID" class="material-control-input filter-option top-filter-1" value="-1" id="top-filter-1" checked="">
                                            <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                                            <span class="material-control-description">-1</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

with this html I have to form A request as ,

```
PROCESSING_TIME in ('checkedval1','checkedval2','checkedval3'),DSPID in ('checedval1')
```

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harifrais/qscn4bxj/25/)

I have tried in my end but i am struck in a point to form request from checked values.Anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started off correct but then would need to find all elements that are connected to each `<H4>` you find. I would use arrays as base as they can be easily joined with the connectors of your choice e.g. using `array.join(',')`.

**Code:**

```
function buildFilter() {

var arrElements = [];
 $('.right-filter-inner').find('h4').each(function(i) {
   var filter = $(this).text();
   var arrChecked = [];
   $('.right-inner-' + filter + ' .material-control-input:checked').each(function() {
     console.log(this);
     arrChecked.push("'" + ($(this).val()) + "'");
   });
   var strFilter = arrChecked.join(',');
   // build a filter list for one filter
   arrElements.push(filter + ' IN ('+ strFilter +')');
 });

 // combine the different filters 
 $('#result').html(arrElements.join(','));
}

buildFilter();
```

Here's an updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/0kjm3h64/) that shows how it works. Just check and uncheck values and click the button to see the changed filter string.

Comment: When uncheck it shows console error as Uncaught ReferenceError: buildFilter is not defined

Comment: Have you checked my fiddle? If you want to change your fiddle with the above code, make sure that the JS "Load type" is set to "No wrap - bottom of body". Otherwise if you click the button it may be that the function name is unknown.

Comment: @Harifrais great to hear! To make sure this question does not remain open would you mind checking my answer as solution in the top left of the answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,  In the checkbox values how to i get without 'ALL' option

Comment: Either filter it out inside the `each` loop or give the checkbox a different CSS class that won't be matched.